# How do I do os.getpid() in C++?

Tags: c++, python

newb here. I am trying to make a c++ program that will read from a named pipe created by python. My problem is, the named pipe created by python uses os.getpid() as part of the pipe name. when i try calling the pipe from c++, i use getpid(). i am not getting the same value from c++. is there a method equivalent in c++ for os.getpid?

thanks!

edit:

sorry, i am actually using os.getpid() to get the session id via ProcessIDtoSessionID(). i then use the session id as part of the pipe name

Comment: No standard C++ way. It depends on your OS, or what library/framework you use. Please provide more info.

Comment: What do you man by "not the same value"? getpid() returns the process id - it will different (possibly) each time it is called.

Comment: Isn't that expected? Since you are using a pipe, they are different processes in the end, right?

Answer (score 4):

You don't get same proccess IDs because your python program and c++ programs are run in different proccesses thus having different process IDs. So generally use a different logic to name your fifo files.

Comment: i see. thanks. i was using os.getpid() as a parameter to pywin32's ProcessIDtoSessionID to get the session ID.

i will try to use a different method. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You **won't** get the same value if you're running as a separate process as each process has their own process ID. Find some other way to identify the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library does not give you anything other than files. You will need to use some other OS specific API.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily retrieve the Python interpreter's PID from your C++ program.

Either assign the named pipe a constant name, or if you really *need* multiple pipes of the same Python program, create a temporary file to which the Python programs write their PIDs (use file locking!) - then you can read the PIDs from the C++ program.